# MemCached documentation is not up to date

Tags: memcached

I have gone through the various sections of documentation of MemCached at the wiki page https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewStart . However I find most of the sections were updated around year 2010/2011. Also I find the latest release of memcached from http://memcached.org/downloads was in May2014. There is a big time gap between documentation updates and the latest release. Why is that?
Is memcached being superseded by any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because memcached has not changed a whole lot since the documentation was written. If you look through the release notes for each release since 2010/2011 you will notice that most of the releases are bug fix releases and those that do add features are usually stats features, support for a new os version, or support for using some lower level api. For the most part the core functionality in memcached has not changed much for a long time.